# Is it possible to use class name which declare in namespace without namespace::

Tags: c++, namespaces

Is it possible to use class name which declare in namespace without namespace?

I tried like this:

```
//MyClass.h
namespace MyNamespace {
  class MyClass;
}

class MyNamespace::MyClass {
  public:
    /* ... */
}

//MyOtherClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
using namespace MyNamespace;

void MyOtherClass::MyFunction() {
  MyClass *myClass = new MyClass;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Complier says "MyClass is ambiguous."

I guess this code would work :

```
//MyOtherClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
using namespace MyNamespace;

void MyOtherClass::MyFunction() {
  MyNamespace::MyClass *myClass = new MyClass;
}
```

But it is uncomfortable for me.
I wanna use 'MyClass' without "MyNamespace::".

Is it possible?

Thanks for your help.

**I got answer** : It is not possible.
C++ classes have own default namespace. If I declare `MyNamespace`, then there is two namespaces associated with `MyClass`. If I use `MyClass` without choosing what namespace I want to use, Compiler feel ambiguous what namespace I really wanted to use. So it would tell me "`MyClass`is ambiguous."

Comment: Does the compiler tell you where the two (or more) definitions of `MyClass` are that it thinks are ambiguous?  What is `MyOtherClass`, and how is it defined?

Comment: Making a "working" [mcve] of your code I [can't replicate your problem](https://godbolt.org/z/6Xpbsm).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm (Sorry for poor English) I made out your word "_definitions of MyClass_" to code like `MyClass *myClass = new MyClass;` . If I am right, the answer is yes. Compiler told me `MyClass` is ambiguous with every code that use `MyClass`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm About your second question, I think how `MyOtherClass` is defined is not the key of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if the below code is all in the same .h file (you did not really clarify)

```
//MyClass.h
namespace MyNamespace {
  class MyClass;
}

class MyNamespace::MyClass {
  public:
    /* ... */
}
```

Then what you are doing a forward declaration of MyNamespace::MyClass in the first part.
You should have something like this in MyClass.h

```
    namespace MyNamespace {
      class MyClass
      {
       public:
        // constructor, methods,...
      }; // end of class declaration
    } // end of namespace
```

and the associated definition in MyClass.cpp

Comment: Thanks for help, but your suggestion doesn't fit on this problem. Well, I got answer on this problem a few minutes ago. C++ classes have own default namespace. If I declare `MyNamespace`, then there is two namespaces associated with `MyClass`. If I use `MyClass` without choosing what namespace I want to use, Compiler feel ambiguous what namespace I really wanted to use. So it would tell me "`MyClass`is ambiguous." Sorry for my poor English, and Thanks for your help.